# Type error evaluating user input: IO () with actual type [[Char]]. Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement the game on which i can move different blocks on the board. I've set the conditions for moving and an actual moving of the blocks, now what i tried to add was a recursive loop on user input, which would ideally solve the game.

That's what i've written:

```
userInput tableArr = do
  str <- getLine
  if str == "help"
    then printHelp tableArr
    else if str == "gg"
      then putStrLn "Game over, you lose"
      else if length str == 3
         then isCorrectInput str tableArr
         else if str == "table"
           then let printer = printTable tableArr in userInput tableArr
           else displayErrorMsg tableArr

isCorrectInput :: String -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
isCorrectInput str tableArr = do
  let val = filter (not . isSpace) str
  let move = val !! 1
  let number = digitToInt(val !! 0)
  let posArr = findBlock (myElem number) tableArr
  if length val == 2
    then (if move == 'R'
            then let newArr = moveRIGHT tableArr number posArr in userInput newArr
            else if move == 'L'
              then let newArr = moveLEFT tableArr number posArr in userInput newArr
              else if move == 'U'
                then let newArr = moveUP tableArr number posArr in userInput newArr
                else if move == 'D'
                  then let newArr = moveDOWN tableArr number posArr in userInput newArr
                  else displayErrorMsg tableArr)
    else displayErrorMsg tableArr

displayErrorMsg tableArr = do
  putStr "Wrong input, type again: "
  userInput tableArr
```

Now a-bit clarification on what's happening here.

Function `userInput` takes in a `[[Char]]` (i have not set the signature cause i got confused on the return type of this thing). Now there's several conditions for the user input, but the error is thrown in `isCorrectInput`. (Also is `let printer = printTable tableArr in userInput tableArr` written correctly? I didn't want to add recursive end to function printTable which basically contains only `putStrLn`s to print out my game board).

Now let's take a quick look at `isCorrectInput`. This evaluates the user input abit more accurately and takes an action based on the user input (Usually the user input is expected in manner "4 R" which means basically block with number 4 to right. Anyways if one of the moving conditions are matched then the move function is called, added to the new variable and then the function `userInput` is called out recursively once again.

The function `displayErrorMsg` is just to display message and call-out recursion again.

Now the error that i'm getting is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[[Char]]'
In the expression: isCorrectInput str tableArr
In the expression:
  if length str == 3 then
      isCorrectInput str tableArr
  else
      if str == "table" then
          let printer = ... in userInput tableArr
      else
          displayErrorMsg tableArr
In the expression:
  if str == "gg" then
      putStrLn "Game over, you lose"
  else
      if length str == 3 then
          isCorrectInput str tableArr
      else
          if str == "table" then
              let ... in userInput tableArr
          else
              displayErrorMsg tableArr
```

I hope that my explanation was clear enough as i'm not a native English speaker and one of you could show what's wrong with my code.

Thank you :)

Comment: How are you learning Haskell? Are you reading some book or something? There are so many wrong things in that code. But that particular error message just reveals simple controversion: you're declaring `isCorrectInput` to be pure function (despite its name, it is not anything like a predicate) but you put `displayErrorMsg` there, which prints something on the screen, thus it's in `IO` monad and cannot be used in pure function.

Comment: I took a class in this fall where we were teached Haskell, Prolog, Ocaml, C and Scala. The project deadline is coming up (this is the project code) and i'm trying to work some things out to get the points. I'm more into imperative programming and writing functional is just not my style, i just want to pass the class and put as much as possible behind my ear. The most difficult thing is with this course that it teaches you the whole language in about 3 weeks and then moves onto really similar one.

Comment: "writing functional is just not my style, i just want to pass the class" That's very sad to hear :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the function `isCorrectInput` isn't in `IO` monad. Look at its type:

```
isCorrectInput :: String -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
```

and the error message

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[[Char]]'
In the expression: isCorrectInput str tableArr
```

Since your is monadic (because of the `do` used) it is assumed that it should return a monadic result. Since it appears to be using the `IO` monad, you should correct its type signature to (note that String = [Char]):

```
isCorrectInput :: String -> [String] -> IO [String]
```

and each expression that represents a result in your function should be a monadic expression or use a `return` in order to put the result in a given monad. So to fix this error, just add `return`:

```
if length str == 3 then
    return (isCorrectInput str tableArr)
else ...
```

My suggestion is to first understand Haskell IO and Monads. The Chapters 9 and 12 of [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) provide the necessary background.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is messy - on more than one level, so bear with me while I try to tidy it up and help you understand this error and most importantly avoid it in the future.

TL,DR for you claim that `isCorrectInput :: String -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]` in the type signature but all the functions at the end of your abundant ifs are of type `IO ()` so the signature should be `isCorrectInput :: String -> [[Char]] -> IO ()` probably (for there are some functions without implementation here).

But first of all try to work with the following principles

- try to avoid `IO ()` where possible and stick to "pure" functions
- use guards/case statements instead of nested `if`s
- unless you have good reasons for it - code "walking" to the right side of the screen - is a bad sign
- write small and understandable functions
- if you cannot figure out the signature of a code piece - use `ghci`

  ```
  Prelude> :type functionnamewhosesignatureidontknow
  ```

  will help you
- read "learn you a haskell for great good" or some other literature linked in the info section of this stackoverflow tag
- if you have a haskell/functional programming user group near you join them

---

Now to your code - I'll update this section as I get more on with it

I try to start with a skeleton of functions just with a type signature and no implementation

`Main.hs`

```
type GameBoard = [String]
data Direction = L|R|U|D deriving (Eq,Show)
type Move = (Int,Direction)

mainLoop :: IO ()
-- checks for abort condition and gives helpful information,
-- while playing the game
mainLoop = undefined

parseMove :: GameBoard -> String -> Maybe Move
-- checks if a given (pure) input string is a valid move for
-- a given game state, for now I use Maybe to indicate all versions of invalid
-- input
parseMove = undefined

help :: IO ()
-- prints the rules of the game
help = undefined

printErr :: String -> IO ()
printErr = undefined
```

now this should compile - let's fill up the `mainLoop` - oh I noticed we want to use the current `GameBoard in that one so add it as a parameter - note that there are techniques to make this a bit more convenient (notably the so called`State` monad)

```
mainLoop :: GameBoard -> IO ()
mainLoop gb = do
   str <- getLine
  case str of "help" -> do help
                           mainLoop gb

              "gg" -> putStrLn "Game Over"

          -- "table" I omit for sake of shortness
              _  -> do let nextMove = parseMove gb str
                       mainLoop (nextBoard gb nextMove)

nextBoard :: GameBoard -> Move -> GameBoard
nextBoard = undefined -- try to implement this one on your own
```

Ooops there's an error in my code - but hey the compiler told us nextMove is `Maybe Move` where `nextBoard` expects a `Move` so tidy that up quickly

```
              _  -> case parseMove gb str
                      of Just nextMove -> mainLoop (nextBoard gb nextMove)
                         _ -> do putStrLn "incorrect move - please repeat"
                                 mainLoop gb
```

next challenge is to tidy up is parsing the input, but first I redefine my `GameBoard`, knowing that haskell is a statically typed language I want to make use of that and actually use this to my advantage

```
type Tile = Empty | Movable | Fixed | Player deriving (Eq)
instance Show Tile where
  -- I usally use my favourite unicode box characters for games like this one
  show Empty   = " "
  show Movable = "0"
  show Fixed   = "#"
  show Player  = "@"
type GameBoard = [[Tile]]
```

first I will split the `String` at the ' ' but how if I don't know the name of that function?

=> use HOOGLE https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%28%5Ba%5D%2C%5Ba%5D%29

and using ghci for the two candidates in `Prelude` we get `break` as the desired one

```
parseMove :: GameBoard -> String -> Maybe Move
-- note despite us changing what Gameboard is this signature has not changed!
-- first of all I assume that number and dir are separated by a space
-- watch out there is still a space at _dir
-- and both tuple entries are still Strings
parseMove gb = do let (_n, _dir) = break (== ' ') str
                  n <- parseInt n
                  dir <- parseDir _dir
                  if canPlayerMove gb (n,dir) then return (n,dir)
                                              else Nothing

  where parseInt :: String -> Maybe Int
        parseInt s = if all isDigit s -- you might import or define `isDigit` yourself
                       then Just (read s)
                       else Nothing
        parseDir :: String -> Maybe Direction
        parseDir "L" = Just L
        parseDir "R" = Just R
        -- ..
        parseDir _ = Nothing

canPlayerMove :: GameBoard -> Move -> Bool
canPlayerMove = undefined -- here you take care that the Game logic is respected
```

I hope you get a bit of a picture how to tidy up code.
Also note that this code is by far the best, I hope I wrote it understandably

Btw. that `do` .. `<-` .. `return` in `parseMove` is a neat trick when working with `Maybe` the right arrow takes a `Maybe value` on the right hand side and pulls out a `value` if it is `Just x`, otherwise the whole computation below that point is discarded and `Nothing` is returned.

Comment: Well, I/O has to come up eventually although, i'm reading a game table in from a txt file. I'll try to keep up with your suggestions but guards are not what i'm used to in programming (mostly javascript/python) and then if-else  conditions seem more familiar and easier for me, however they might not be as efficient.

Comment: Could you give ma an advice how could i set it to print out and continue on command `table`. Currently it'll just go on with userInput tableArr and not printing the table.

Comment: you can nest `do`-blocks inside `do`-blocks - see the `_ -> do let ..` for example